Converting "improper" partial order to total order
I suspect that if I knew what to search for, this would be easy to find an answer to, but I don't know what the proper name is for the input portion of the problem statement.

I have a set and a partial ordering of that set that might not be proper (in that it might contain elements that form cycles). I want to convert to a proper total order that has a minimum (or near minimum if that's significantly easier) number of elements that violate the original ordering.
As it happens, I expect that the partial order will be "mostly proper", most of the time. Proper orders will be common, but so will cases with only a few "inversion". However I can't guarantee that in all cases and expect to occasional face cases that are "noisy" and still need to deal with them.

I suspect that this is a well understood problem, but I'm coming up blank for everything I've thought of to search for so far.

Since you imply "might have cycles" is the only problem, does that mean that your "improper partial order"s will have every pair of elements comparable?

Anyway, it sounds like you really want graph theory. Like, an "improper partial order" is essentially a (connected?) directed graph. And you want to turn that into a... I think you'd call it a directed path graph.

@MarkS. Most pairs of elements will not have a (directly) defined ordering and there might even be disjoint groups. While far from the expected cases, I'd like to be able to pick a total ordering for anything from "no two elements have a defined order" to "every element is both before and after every other element".

Are you acquainted with any of the standard terminology in order theory? Terms like incomparability, chain, and antichain? It sure seems like you are using some terms in contradictory ways. As an example, what might you mean by saying that one element is “both before and after” another? How does one get a partial order out of things like that?

What do you mean by “proper” and “improper”?

@PaulTanenbaum figuring out the terms that are relevant to my question is kinda the point of this question. The set I'm dealing with is expected to be mostly incomparable (the ordering relation is a sparse graph). By "improper" I'm dealing with the issue that the "ordering relation" I'm given is effectively a lookup table and isn't necessarily transitive; $(a\le b)\land(b\le c)\land(c\le a)$ might be encountered. A "proper" order is what you normally think of and what I'm trying to generate.

Okay. So without transitivity it can’t be called a partial order. And how would you prefer to break cycles? And will there be other failures of transitivity, those of the form $a<b$, $b<c$, but $a$ and $c$ incomparable?

@PaulTanenbaum you're seeing why I'm using the invented term "improper partial order". As said in the OP, I want to break cycles by minimizing the number of pair where the original order relation orders them opposite to the generated total order. Other than that, it doesn't even need to be deterministic. And your last example is exactly what I was referring to as things being "mostly incomparable" so; yes.

In terms of the graph of your relation, I guess you could find a spanning tree, and then put back any edges that form cycles that are not problematic. I'm not sure if this is minimal, but given that it's the directed cycles that are causing your problem, it might be close.
